# react-native material top tab navigator swipe disable depending on screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Wanna make only Map component swipe-disabled but the entire screens were applied when using "swipeEnabled".

How can I do?

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      swipeEnabled={false}  // <- Screens can be swiped but it is applied to every screen.
      {...}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Map"
        component={Map}
      /> 
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaView} />
      <Tabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass a state value to `swipeEnabled` and update the value to `false` if you're on the `Map` screen like this:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {
  const [swipeEnabled, setSwipeEnabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        swipeEnabled={swipeEnabled}
        screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) => {
          if (route.name === 'Map' && navigation.isFocused()) {
            setSwipeEnabled(false);
          } else if (route.name !== 'Map' && navigation.isFocused()) {
            setSwipeEnabled(true);
          }
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={Map} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible directly on tab screen to restrict with the `swipeEnabled` options property.

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Map"
  options={{ swipeEnabled: false }}
  component={MapScreen}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As swipeEnabled={swipeEnable} is depreciated you must use this is screenOption in Tab.Navigator

screenOption comes with various options one of them is swipeEnabled

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
    
const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
              swipeEnabled: false,
              tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              elevation: 0,
              shadowOpacity: 0,
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
            },
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
              fontSize: 12,
              textTransform: 'capitalize',
            },
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#000',
            tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }
          }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={Map} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```